# Simple Facebook "Share Link"

Tags: javascript, facebook

I am working on a site where posts are made and I'd like to give visitors the ability to "share" a particular post that they link on their timeline. I have never done any social media integration, but I followed the instructions via the FB API and am still having problems. It's easier to show you than try to explain it. Go to http://www.badcustomerbureau.com/ and click on any of the Share links at the top of any post. Instead of sharing the post you clicked on, it tries to share a generic post with the same photo every time (photo of a dog). I used the code generator on the FB help site and it still has this issue. Please help!

I did receive one suggestion from a member of this site, but I am still seeing the same behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I think its already working. I've tried it before in my own website http://socialviralworld.com/. You just have to login first and see the changes.

See image:

[image: see image]

Comment: I wish...every "share" link attempts to share the same article.  I'm out of ideas.  I made the meta tags on the post.aspx page dynamic...not sure what else to try?